# How to edit file using QXmlStreamReader and QXmlStreamWriter?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, file, edit

So far I was using QXmlStreamReader in Qt to read data from an xml file and QXmlStreamWriter to overwrite a file.

I am wondering now though, how can I read a file to go through it and when I find the element that I am interested in, edit it using xml writer?

I Dont think both QXmlStreamReader and QXmlStreamWriter can use the same file at the same time.

Comment: You could write to a temporary file then rename it if you make changes to the XML.  Or depending on the size of the file, you could write it into a QString and then stream the string out to the file.

Comment: You shouldn't write into the file directly anyway, that'd be very fragile (and possibly unsafe, think of symlink attacks). If your application or the computer crashes during writing the file, it would end up corrupted. Write to a temp file and when successfully finished, overwrite the file in an atomic operation by renaming the temp file to the real one. See QSaveFile.